# How can I create a UML graph by code and I can search characters in graph?

Tags: uml, markdown, dot, program-flow

I want to create a program flow graph, but I don't want to draw it by Mouse. I can draw a simple graph by markdown or mermaid, but they are too simple.

For example:
[image]
this is generated by Typora Mermaid. All items are html.

But I want to modify more details. For example, font highlighting, adding parentheses in content, etc. I also want to generate graphics that look better.

Another Example:
[image]
This is generated by graphviz, if I export it as svg, I can retrieve characters.

But after I insert it in Typora, and export markdown as a.html. However, I can't search characters from svg in a.html, because its label is **img**. I'm not familiar with HTML, I don't know how to handle this.

I want to find a tool that can render dot language into html, and can work with markdown, How to achieve it? Or any better choices?

Comment: Why do you want this? What do you mean by 'retrieve items' ? Why can't you retrieve items by reading the dot file? Maybe PlantUML is something for you?

Comment: I'm reviewing other people's codes, I want to draw a graph to help me understand program logic. And I hope I can search characters in graph instead of source file because I want to show it in web and visitors can search characters in graph. @www.admiraalit.nl

Comment: Thank you, your question is much more clear now. Unfortunately, I don't have the answer. I will upvote your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I should just generate a **svg** file by dot. A good way to add it in markdown is using html label:`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>`. And chrome would render it.

I'm not sure whether this question is able to keep, but I will keep it until someone asks me to delete it or it's a repeating question.

Here is how I search in a svg.
[image]

Comment: how do you will retrieve items in it, placing each item in a group with an _id_ (`<g id="foo">...</g>`) ?

Comment: Well, I voted to close your question since it's simply too broad. There are thousands of ways to do what you want. Anyhow I'd recommend to use a UML modeling tool since UML is not about diagramming but about modeling.

Comment: @bruno How about some self-advertising? ;-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian I am too modest for that ... or too lazy to do it ^^

Comment: @Thomas Kilian I'm new of diagramming, I just want to make the graphics to help me understand program logic. And "UML" seems like an appropriate name for it? And please suggest me some advice?

Comment: @bruno Hi, I update me answer, I didn't add html labels in it, I just export it as svg, and I can search characters in chrome.

Comment: Again: UML is not about diagramming. You won't make use of UML by using a drawing tool. Choose a UML modeling tool. Else stay with pencil/paper or a white board.